# Pandas Normalizing dict with multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of `dicts`. Each `dict` has nested `dicts` and these `dicts` has list of `dicts`. It's complicated so I gave an example below:

A sample `dict` from the list of `dicts`:

```
{
    "episodeStream": {
        "episodes": [
            {
                "timestamp": 1629908450,
                "data": {
                    "id": "001",
                    "version": "1.02",
                    "componentVersions": {
                        "xcomponent": "1.00",
                        "ycomponent": "1.20"
                    },
                    "adresses": [],
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1629908932,
                "data": {
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "type": "type0",
                            "address": "ffeeddccbbaa",
                            "interfaceid": {
                                "xid": "123123",
                                "yid": "321321"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "directLinkConnection": false
                }
            },
            ...
            ...
            ... more dicts where data field not necessarily same as above
            ...
            ...
        ],
        "deprecatedEpisodes": []
    },
    "header": {
        "namespace": "test",
        "message": "testmessage 123",
        "references": {}
    }
}
```

This is one of the dictionaries in the list of `dicts`. There are lots of dictionaries in the list like `[dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, ...]` and each dictionary is in the same structure.

I want to add these to a Pandas Dataframe. I am not sure how a complex dict such as this could be a dataframe. If I just use pd.from_records, the columns would be **"episodeStream"** and **"header"** and everything in "episodeStream" and "header" dictionaries would be their values.

So instead of `pd.from_records`, I tried `pd.json_normalize` without additional arguments. And the columns are:

```
episodeStream.episodes    episodeStream.deprecatedEpisodes    header.namespace    header.message    header.references
```

and that is not what I want because I also want the timestamp and data columns inside episodes for every episode.

I tried to use it with `record_path` argument and it gave me a `KeyError: 'episodes'` because of the `record_path` argument of `pd.json_normalize`

```
records = [r for r in reader]        # records is a list of dicts
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
df = pd.json_normalize(records, 'episodes')
return df
```

I want a dataframe like below where:
episodeStreamId is *th* `dict` in the list of `dicts`,
episodesId is *th* episode dict in the episodes list

```
     episodeStreamId    episodesId    timestamp    data
0    0                  0             1629908450   "id": "001", "version": "1.02", "componentVersions": {"xcomponent": "1.00", "ycomponent": "1.20"}, "adresses": []
1    0                  1             1629908932   "links": [{"type": "type0", "address": "ffeeddccbbaa", "interfaceid": {"xid": "123123", "yid": "321321"}
     ...
     ...
     ...
120  1                  0             1629914424   "id": "002", "version": "1.02", "componentVersions": {"xcomponent": "1.00", "ycomponent": "1.20"}, "adresses": []
121  1                  1             1629914459   "links": [{"type": "type0", "address": "ddffaaccbbee", "interfaceid": {"xid": "444333", "yid": "222333"}
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

How would you turn a list of `dicts` like this to a Pandas DataFrame?

Edit: A figure of my data:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what your expected data frame look like?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I updated my question

Comment: Where is `header` in your final dataframe?

Comment: @PanwenWang There is a list named records that contains dictionaries. Every dictionary has two dictionaries inside: episodeStream and header. Header dictionary comes after episodeStream dictionary like the sample dictionary I gave in my question. Every dictionary in this list in this format: a episodeStream dictionary containing a list of dictionary and a header dictionary containing values. I am not particularly interested in header field. I added a figure in question so you can understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `records` with your record list, try:

```py
import json
import pandas

records = [...]

data = (
    {
        'episodeStreamId': esid,
        'episodesId' : eid,
        'timestamp' : episode['timestamp'],
        'data': json.dumps(episode['data'])
    } 
    for eid, epistream in enumerate(records)
    for esid, episode in enumerate(epistream['episodeStream']['episodes']) 
)

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

```
   episodeStreamId  episodesId   timestamp                                               data
0                0           0  1629908450  {"id": "001", "version": "1.02", "componentVer...
1                1           0  1629908932  {"links": [{"type": "type0", "address": "ffeed...
```